# How do I map words to functionalities using machine learning?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, mapping, neural-network, deep-learning

I'm doing a project which involves getting inputs from the user and mapping them to functionalities provided by a system. For example, the user might say "alert" which has to be mapped to the "alarm" functionality. Similarly, "wake up" should be mapped to "detect motion" or "detect sound" and so on.

How do I do this using machine learning? 
How can I train for this type of purpose without having to create a synthetic dataset, like training from existing literature?
How can I incorporate active learning into this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this with ML approaches,
This is a classification problem, You must know all of your targets(e.g: alarm),
then create a dataset that map some words to tagrets(e.g alert => alarm, help me => alarm,...) and train the ML algorithms with this dataset.

Then you can test some words or sentences. For example when someone write 'alrt' it could be mapped to => alarm

Although this model is not exact.

You can search for some approach like: TF-IDF or TEXT Classification
This Could be usefull to start: https://www.kaggle.com/c/word2vec-nlp-tutorial/details/part-1-for-beginners-bag-of-words

Comment: That sounds good, but what if something that isn't already in the dataset comes up? Like the user might input "let me know when its 9 PM", for which he/she wants an alarm to be set up? Is there a way to incorporate active learning into this project?

Comment: @Muhammad It depend to your data set, If you create a good and comprehensive data set, it can realize this sentences